# What is the purpose of the pacibsp and retab instructions?

Tags: macos, assembly, arm64, disassembly

I'm trying to learn ARM64 architecture using macOS (running on the Apple's M2 chip.) I'm studying this small function (that checks OS version):

```
libswiftCore.dylib`Swift._stdlib_isOSVersionAtLeast(Builtin.Word, Builtin.Word, Builtin.Word) -> Builtin.Int1:

    0x19d915ea4 <+0>:  pacibsp 
->  0x19d915ea8 <+4>:  stp    x29, x30, [sp, #-0x10]!
    0x19d915eac <+8>:  mov    x29, sp
    0x19d915eb0 <+12>: mov    x3, x2
    0x19d915eb4 <+16>: mov    x2, x1
    0x19d915eb8 <+20>: mov    x1, x0
    0x19d915ebc <+24>: mov    w0, #0x1
    0x19d915ec0 <+28>: bl     0x19db25cb4               ; __isPlatformVersionAtLeast
    0x19d915ec4 <+32>: cmp    w0, #0x0
    0x19d915ec8 <+36>: cset   w0, ne
    0x19d915ecc <+40>: ldp    x29, x30, [sp], #0x10
    0x19d915ed0 <+44>: retab
```

Can someone explain the purpose of the `pacibsp` and `retab` instructions there?

Comment: In short, security :) See for example [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20220819-00/?p=107020)

Comment: Did you look them up in an AArch64 manual?  Is `retab` similar to `ret`?

Comment: @PeterCordes: I did, but the official ARM64 instruction docs weren't clear. That Raymond Chen article is interesting, Thanks.